# Memory leakage with following code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is the code where I am having memory leaks:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reach = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorSy stemDefault, "google.com"); 

SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags;
SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reach, &flags);

[flags release];
[reach release];
```

Those release don't do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, the `SCNetworkConnectionFlags` is an `enum`, so it doesn't have to be released. Remove the `[flags release]` and problem solved.

Moving on, the `SCNetworkReachabilityRef` is released through

```
CFRelease(reach);
```

Comment: This answer should be correct: if you use a Foundation-based memory allocation, it would make sense to use a Foundation-based release.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very good way of remembering it, if you haven't called `[... alloc]` or `[... new...]`, then you shouldn't call `[... release]`.